# Non-standard proof that every $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^k)$ has Lebesgue points almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, inequality, lebesgue-integral, alternative-proof

I have stubbornly been attempting to prove that every Lebesgue integrable function $f$ has Lebesgue points almost everywhere, i.e., satisfies
$$
\lim_{r\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{m(B_r)}\int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)-f(x)|\ dy=0
$$
for almost all $x\in\mathbb{R}^k$, by my own means. Every proof of this result I have found utilizes the Hardy-Littlewood Maximal function, and the related inequality.

My question is this: Is there some proof of the above result that doesn't rely on the Maximal function, preferably one with comparable brevity to the proof given in, for instance, Rudin's RCA?

Comment: There are probabilistic proofs using martingale theory. But deep down, a maximal inequality creeps in (Doob's inequality)

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you for the response, I will admit those proofs probably go far over my head as my knowledge currently stands. However, I am excited to announce I have just discovered the Vitali Covering Theorem, and it seems to be exactly the machinery which I was lacking in my attempt toward an independently motivated proof of this interesting theorem. I believe I can salvage my work to obtain a proof, using a very basic form of this covering theorem in place of the HL-Maximal function. I will post a sketch of the proof if I turn out to be successful.

Comment: Vitali's covering allows you to extend some results to more general measures. Still a maximal inequality crept in.

Comment: The proof in Evans and Gariepy's *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions* (theorem 1.32) doesn't use maximal inequalities. They first prove a stronger Radon-Nikodym theorem, with the heavy lifting being done by the Besicovitch covering theorem, so there's certainly a price to pay (that is not an easy result).